# How to do union of multiple tables with where clause and order by in GORM (golang)

Tags: go, sql-order-by, union, where-clause, go-gorm

I'm trying to do union of multiple tables with selected columns and run where clause and order by clause on the resultset. How do I write this in GORM (Golang)

I tried the following snippet, but didn't run the where clause and order by clause in the DB query:

```
var union []map[string]interface{}
database.CONNECTION.Raw("? UNION ?",
    database.CONNECTION.Select(ContentAttributes).Model(&model1{}),
    database.CONNECTION.Select(ContentAttributes).Model(&model2{}),
).Where("id > ?", 1).Order("Name").Scan(&union)
```

N.B. `ContentAttributes` is a slice of string which contains the attributes I want to select.

It's running the following query:

```
SELECT "id","name","created_at","updated_at" FROM "model1" WHERE "model1"."deleted_at" IS NULL UNION SELECT "id","name","created_at","updated_at" FROM "model2" WHERE "model2"."deleted_at" IS NULL
```

I expected this to run the where condition and the order by clause on the union resultset. But it just did union and collected the results in the `union` variable. Please suggest a way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the cleanest way to do it but it works.

```
var db = database.CONNECTION
var union []map[string]interface{}
var raw = "SELECT * (? UNION ?) union WHERE union.id > ? ORDER BY union.name"

db.Raw(raw,
    db.Select("*").Model(&model1{}),
    db.Select("*").Model(&model2{}),
    1
).Scan(&union)
```